# Issue in raising records with click button commands more than one record

Tags: jquery

my Issue is I changed dropping items by selection from drop down list to be by click on button, but when I click for the first item it drop one item normally and in the second it drop the item two times on two records!! and in the third it drop the item in three times n three records ...etc

this is my code

```
//to get the elements by document.ready function//

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#DropDownList2").change(function()
  {
 // button to drop down the record to table//

 $('#button1').click(function(){
  GetData($("#DropDownList2 option:selected").text());
  });
  });
    });
    function GetData(itemName){

    $.ajax({
    url:'Default2.aspx?brand='+$("#DropDownList1 option:selected").text()+'&item='+itemName+'&itemId='+$("#DropDownList2 option:selected").val()+'',

    type:'GET',
    success: function(data)
    {
    if($("#tableContent tr:last").html() == undefined)
    {
    $("#tableContent").html(data);
    }
    else{
    $("#tableContent tr:last").after(data);
    }
    }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#DropDownList2").change(function() {}
```